# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core. Why does the DotNetCompilerPlatform rely on an old Build.Utilities.Core?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, .net-assembly

I downloaded a sample C# project from github: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetDocs

But I got an error message when building:
**The 'KillProcess' task could not be loaded from the assembly** '......Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.3.6.0\build\net472....\tasks\DotNetCompilerPlatformTasks.dll'.
**Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0**,...' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 update 5. The target framework for my project is .NET Framework 4.8.

And I have installed the Nuget packages:
**Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform v3.6.0
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core v16.9.0**

According to the error message, it seems that the Nuget package DotNetCompilerPlatform needs an old Build.Utilities.Core v14.0.0.0 while the one I have installed is the latest version V16.9.0.

But I failed to nuget Install-Package the v14.0.0.0 after I Uninstall-Package v16.9.0.

Is it possible to config the DotNetCompilerPlatform in order to use the latest Build.Utilities.Core?

Thank you all. Have a good weekend.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a Visual Studio that is 3 versions behind the latest?

Comment: Hi Johnson, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**In my side**, I found that the issue is related to the verification of these installed NuGet packages on the local computer.

**First of all**, you should make the full path of **ProductsApp** folder a bit shorter。 Otherwise, you will face the problem of `The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters`.

So you have to copy the **ProductsApp** folder into `C:\` or `D:\` directly and then open it under VS IDE on that path.

After that, reinstall the nuget packages once.

Run

`update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**

After that, if you still face the issue, you have to add `bindredirect` for that new dll under `web.config` file and it can use the latest one if you uses the functiion from the latest one. And it just cannot find the old version of the dll since you have used the code from the old one under code editor.

The workaround is to add bindredirect for it:

**1)** open web.config file:

**2)** add these：

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      .....
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" publicKeyToken="xxx" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.1.0.0" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
```

**3)** then delete `bin` and `obj` folder and then rebuild again.